# How we can prove this relation for Kendall's tau

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, survival, nonparametric, association-measure

I found the relation below while studying the measure of dependence. How we can prove this relation about Kendall's tau?
$$
\tau = 4\int\int H(x, y)\, h(x,y)\, dx\, dy - 1
$$

Comment: Please explain what $H$ and $h$ refer to.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks similar but not the same ,here the relation in general and for kendalls tau for copula it is specific for the archimedean family of copula

Comment: H: the joint distribution function and  h : the p.d.f of H

Comment: I have noticed this relationship in the book "Continuous Bivariate Distributions"
Of the authors " N. Balakrishnan · Chin-Diew Lai " Chapter 4 page 155 @whuber

Comment: I think we could use this relation 4 ∫∫ C(x, y) dC(x, y) dx dy − 1 and by Skalar's Thm we can prove that Kendall's tau τ = 4 ∫ ∫ H(x, y) h(x, y) dx dy – 1 @Alecos Papadopoulos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $(X_1,Y_1)$ be a bivariate continuous random vector, independently and identically distributed with the vector $(X_2, Y_2)$. $X_1$ may be dependent with $Y_1$, and $X_2$ may be dependent with $Y_2$. Kendall's tau is defined as

$$\tau_{X,Y} = \Pr[(X_1-X_2)(Y_1-Y_2) > 0] - \Pr[(X_1-X_2)(Y_1-Y_2) < 0]$$

Now, we have

$$\Pr[(X_1-X_2)(Y_1-Y_2) < 0] = 1-\Pr[(X_1-X_2)(Y_1-Y_2) > 0] $$

$$\implies \tau_{X,Y} =2\Pr[(X_1-X_2)(Y_1-Y_2) > 0] -1$$

The probability of the event $\{(X_1-X_2)(Y_1-Y_2) > 0\}$ is equal to the sum of the probabilities of the joint events $\{X_1>X_2, Y_1>Y_2\}$ and $\{X_1<X_2, Y_1<Y_2\}$ ,

$$\Pr[(X_1-X_2)(Y_1-Y_2) > 0] = \Pr[X_1>X_2, Y_1>Y_2] + \Pr[X_1<X_2, Y_1<Y_2]$$

Note also that because the two $X$'s are i.i.d and the two $Y$'s likewise, we have

$$\Pr[X_1>X_2, Y_1>Y_2] = \Pr[X_1<X_2, Y_1<Y_2]$$

Combining all we have arrived at

$$\tau_{X,Y} = 4\Pr[X_1<X_2, Y_1<Y_2] -1$$

Now, let's translate $\Pr[X_1<X_2, Y_1<Y_2]$. I will initially compact the bivariate vector into $(X_i,Y_i)=\mathbf w_i$. Let  $H(x_i,y_i) \equiv H(\mathbf w_i)$ be the joint distribution function of $(X_i,Y_i)$ (for index $1$ as well as for index $2$), and $h(x_i,y_i) \equiv h(\mathbf w_i)$ the corresponding density.

Then (remembering that $\mathbf w_1$ is independent from $\mathbf w_2$, so their joint distribution is the product of their bivariate marginals) we have
$$\Pr[X_1<X_2, Y_1<Y_2] = \Pr[\mathbf w_1 < \mathbf w_2]$$
$$=\int h(\mathbf w_2) \int^{\mathbf w_2} h(\mathbf t_1) d\mathbf t_1 d\mathbf w_2,$$

where the integrals are bi-dimensional (hence the informality as regards the limits of integration). Then
$$\Pr[X_1<X_2, Y_1<Y_2] = \int h(w_2) H(w_2) dw_2$$

and reverting back to writing the bivariate vector explicitly the RHS integral is

$$\Pr[X_1<X_2, Y_1<Y_2] = \int \int _{S_{X,Y}}h(x,y) H(x,y)dx dy.$$

Losing the "2" index is inconsequential because these are dummy variables of integration, the juice is in the functions comprising the integrand, as well as in the range of integration: $S_{X,Y}$ is the joint support.

So we have arrived at

$$\tau_{X,Y} = 4\int \int _{S_{X,Y}}h(x,y) H(x,y)dx dy -1 =4E[H(X,Y)] -1$$

In the last expression, $H(X,Y)$ is not treated as the distribution function of $X,Y$ but as a single-valued bivariate function of these two random variables.

Comment: Could you explain what "$S_{X,Y}$" refers to and what these "basic principles" might be?

Comment: @whuber Will take care of it in a few hours

Comment: been a minute, but would be helpful to me if you could answer whuber's question

Comment: @RobertHickman Yeah, I got distracted. Please see the re-written answer.