# Bivariate probability inequality into an integral

Tags: joint-distribution, bivariate, kendall-tau

I am having a hard time understanding one (I assume simple) part of a proof (see the link below if you want the whole thing).

Let the two bivariate continuous random vectors:
$(X_1,Y_1), (X_2,Y_2)$ be iid and $H(X,Y)$ be the joint distribution function of (,) (for index 1 as well as for index 2).
$$ \Pr[X_1<X_2, Y_1<Y_2] = \int \int _{S_{X,Y}} \Pr[X_1\leq x_2, Y_1\leq y_2]dH(x,y) $$

For the left hand side, $S_{X,Y} $ refers to the support of the variable. The original post (see link below) does not include $x_2,y_2$ in the solution, it just says $x,y$ but I added them for clarity.

How does one go from the right side to the left? 
My attempt:

$$ =\int_{X \epsilon (-\infty,\infty)} Pr[ X_1<x_2,Y_1<Y_2 | X_2=x_2]dH(X,Y)    $$
$$ =\int_{X \epsilon (-\infty,\infty)} \int_{Y \epsilon (-\infty,\infty)}  Pr[ X_1<x_2,Y_1<y_2 | X_2=x_2, Y_2=y_2]dH(X,Y)    $$

My question is also that I am not sure I understand that the limit is the $ -\infty,\infty$. Is it because $ X_1,X_2$ follow the same distribution? 
Would you please help me being very specific about the steps?
Thank you.

The original post is this one. It just says

[How we can prove this relation for Kendall's tau](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419133/how-we-can-prove-this-relation-for-kendalls-tau/419447#419447)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation
$$\Pr[X_1<X_2, Y_1<Y_2] = \int \int _{S_{X,Y}} \Pr[X_1\leq x_2, Y_1\leq y_2]\,\text{d}H(x,y)$$
should indeed be
$$\Pr[X_1<X_2, Y_1<Y_2] = \int _{S_{X,Y}} \Pr[X_1\leq x, Y_1\leq y]\,\text{d}H(x,y)$$
or
$$\Pr[X_1<X_2, Y_1<Y_2] = \int _{S_{X,Y}} \Pr[X_1\leq x_2, Y_1\leq y_2]\,\text{d}H(x_2,y_2)$$
to be coherent. It follows from
$$\Pr[X_1<X_2, Y_1<Y_2] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_{(-\infty,X_2)}(X_1)\mathbb{I}_{(-\infty,Y_2)}(Y_1)]$$
being decomposed as
\begin{align*}\Pr[X_1<X_2, Y_1<Y_2] &=  \mathbb{E}^{X_2,Y_2}\{\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_{(-\infty,X_2)}(X_1)\mathbb{I}_{(-\infty,Y_2)}(Y_1)]\,|\,{X_2,Y_2}\}\\
&=  \mathbb{E}^{X_2,Y_2}\{\Pr[X_1<X_2, Y_1<Y_2\,|\,X_2,Y_2]\}\\
&= \int_{S_{X,Y}} \Pr[X_1<X_2, Y_1<Y_2\,|\,X_2=x_2,Y_2=y_2]\,\text{d}H(x_2,y_2)\\
&= \int _{S_{X,Y}} \Pr[X_1\leq x_2, Y_1\leq y_2]\,\text{d}H(x_2,y_2)
\end{align*}
since $(X_1,Y_1)$ is independent from $(X_2,Y_2)$